# how to find out all properties of an object in lua?

Tags: object, properties, lua

Is there any way of getting all the non-nil parameters / properties
of an object? I found this: `getmetadata(self.xxxx)` and i am looking for something like: `getalldata(self).`

I'm currently working on a project where lua is involved. Unfortunately, there is no complete reference and i have to use precompiled stuff.

I hope you are able to understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to assume that when you are referring to "objects" you are meaning "lua tables with an `__index` metatable pointing to other tables". If that is not the case, this answer will not help you.

If your object structure is made with tables (this is, all `__indexes` are tables) then you can "parse them up" to obtain all the properties and inherited properties.

If you have any function as `__index` then what you ask is impossible; there's no way to get the "list of values for which a function returns a non-nil value".

In the first case, the code would look like this:

```
function getAllData(t, prevData)
  -- if prevData == nil, start empty, otherwise start with prevData
  local data = prevData or {}

  -- copy all the attributes from t
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    data[k] = data[k] or v
  end

  -- get t's metatable, or exit if not existing
  local mt = getmetatable(t)
  if type(mt)~='table' then return data end

  -- get the __index from mt, or exit if not table
  local index = mt.__index
  if type(index)~='table' then return data end

  -- include the data from index into data, recursively, and return
  return getAllData(index, data)
end
```

But remember, if any of your `__index`es is a function, there is no way to get all the properties; at least not from Lua.

Answer (score 4):

I believe objects are just a table, so you should be able to iterate over the properties as any other table:

```
for i,v in ipairs(your_object) do body end
```

Comment: this only gives you numeric key "properties". I thing you meant `pairs` instead of `ipairs`.

Comment: Yes, which is what egarcia includes in his more complete solution.  Thanks for pointing out this bug.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote my own printObject code.. here it is

```
function printObj(obj, hierarchyLevel) 
  if (hierarchyLevel == nil) then
    hierarchyLevel = 0
  elseif (hierarchyLevel == 4) then
    return 0
  end

  local whitespace = ""
  for i=0,hierarchyLevel,1 do
    whitespace = whitespace .. "-"
  end
  io.write(whitespace)

  print(obj)
  if (type(obj) == "table") then
    for k,v in pairs(obj) do
      io.write(whitespace .. "-")
      if (type(v) == "table") then
        printObj(v, hierarchyLevel+1)
      else
        print(v)
      end           
    end
  else
    print(obj)
  end
end
```

This is the opposite approach then the post before used.
Go through all key value pairs in the table. If the value of one index is a table, go through this table.
This solution will not get the upwards metatables like the other post did