# Python has dir(obj) and help(obj), is there an equivalent in Lua?

Tags: python, lua, introspection

For any one unfamiliar with those two methods in Python...

`dir` returns a list of methods/properties of a specific object.

`help` returns an objects [doc strings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: As for `dir()`, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636596/how-to-find-out-all-properties-of-an-object-in-lua) might help (note that LUA doesn't have objects in the Python sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua has no concept of "doc strings."

All Lua objects are tables (or userdata, but you can't inspect userdata from Lua code. Well not in Lua 5.1; in 5.2, you can do it if the user who created the userdata wants you to). Therefore, you can just use existing table methods to iterate over the contents of a table:

```
for k, v in pairs(obj) do
  --Do stuff with k(ey) and v(alue)
end
```

Note that this will invoke metamethods, so the *true* contents of the table aren't known. Then again, if the person who created that object wanted you to have the true contents, he wouldn't have protected them with metamethods.

Answer (score 5):

Lets fun:

```
function dir(obj)
    for k, v in pairs(obj) do print(k) end
end
```

that is a similar python "dir" function in Lua.